# Input string was not in a correct format after passing a string value with comma seperated value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have a function in testdb.context.cs which executes a procedure in database,one of my parameter is string and it may/may not take comma split values ("2,3") mapped datatype of procedure is nvarchar but during execution of that proc from my code it is throwing error input string not in correct format

code:

public virtual ObjectResult Getdata_Result(Nullable Id, string country)
        {
            var IDParameter = Id.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("Id", Id) :
                new ObjectParameter("Id", typeof(int));

```
        var CountryParameter = country!= null ?
            new ObjectParameter("country", country) :
            new ObjectParameter("country", typeof(string));
```

return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("Usp_Getdata",IDParameter,CountryParameter )
}

any advice is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my model context was not updated. After making changes in the procedure your model context has to updated. Right click on ER Diagram>click Update model>Refresh your procedure